# Animation speed as linear function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you make an animation in jquery go faster by the second? Just like gravity I want the animation to speed up with time (as a linear function)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery UI` provides few 'speeding up' options. One of them is `easeInQuart`.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#a').animate({left: '500px'}, 1000, 'easeInQuart');
    $('#b').animate({left: '500px'}, 1000, 'linear');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="a" style="background-color: red; position: relative; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
<br/><br/>
<div id="b" style="background-color: red; position: relative;width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: @user7548524 Upvote&mark question?